# dynimacally generte a json object

Tags: java, json

```
String json = "{\"loginForm\": [{\"formType\": \"questionAndAnswer\",\"id\": 164422,\"row\": [{\"label\": \"What is the name of your state?\",\"field\": [{\"id\":\"SQandA--QUESTION_1-1\",\"value\": \""+answer1+"\"}]},{\"label\": \"What is the name of your first school\",\"field\": [{\"id\":\"SQandA--QUESTION_2-2\",\"value\": \""+answer2+"\"}]}]}],"+dataset+"}";
```

this json contains questions and answer in it and its hard coded in my code what should i do to dynamically generate it as i want to remove the hard code and call it dynamically.

Comment: Maybe using `String.format()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class file with your json fields and then convert the class object to json using Jackson apis.

```
private String getJsonFromJava (Object obj) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String jsonInString = "";
    try {
        jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to parse object to prepare JSON string", e);
    }
    return jsonInString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write logic to create json using the inputs. If you are creating the json in JS then look at sample code below. Or you can do the same login in server side - java etc?

```
function createJSON() {
    jsonObj = [];
    $("input[questions]").each(function() {

        var q= $(this).attr("Question");
        var ans= $(this).val();

        item = {}
        item ["question"] = id;
        item ["answer"] = ans;

        jsonObj.push(item);
    });

    console.log(jsonObj);
}
```